# zlib decompress() only decode the first line

Tags: python, utf-8, compression, zlib

I have a large dictionary (more than 1000 entries) called `idf` and I want to store all of it's `values()` in a compressed .txt file. This is my code

```
for key in idf:
    data = str(idf[key])
    compressed_index = zlib.compress(data.encode('ISO-8859-1'))
    with open(current_inverted_index, "ab") as my_file:
        my_file.write(compressed_index)
```

Once the compression of over, the size of my new .txt file is (443MB) and the first few lines look like this:

```
xúãÆVw∞∞4422–5000T∑R®6¨≠’Q@76âõa»òÉdå
1ıò[Ädåå±»XÇm16Ø≠ç»5%xúµö;í$7DØ2ûúUI+O7êØ–I∫ª*¿ÍŸ e ÿâÆÆÊH$‡˛˘˜/øˇ1W.%˝öR ø¸ˆıwÓ˘«W˘Ò’r˚Ò’≥>µÙ|SèÎ˘3ü9?ﬂŸzõ=_}üûØj~Fw[ˇ¸Û„ÎÁ…ã&/Îô/€3$Ø©   ûm<Oœ–RüwVüOYsñ¢üÆtŒdl”‘ûÍ≥â¢aââü+ÈÎTı]}˛ˆŒoµŸÁ≈*œS”j5˜Á'zπ,Î«ú}uΩy˛ïgãıUM;KM¥kç2ôb…ûS6zå¢°C¶—≤CfºÊ‘Î¨ ßû◊ÛzvΩ÷÷üÔÊ–Óµ@≈J˘±ã
Œê5ô∂i3üˆ®≤áu-•a1¥idÎÁœé(œÎ5t»G∂≈pY†>/ ÁÿÆ±-„π≠◊pgùXBF¿8≤ZÔ2∏æörÔ‘ÃM ÂC3wY.ëÕ≤∆Á%ØÈI√≥ÜcJπ0∑À'‡ê7ãòM€œ$EP.Cèì¡v^\î"h◊.§Oç∆ûmîcTNÙA>¬äX¸¸⁄øÏŸáfî€eú<RÑ#-)º6ç%ë≤î∆∏_‰ﬂv∆U&hMªl⁄•5·Iß4˘F«`7µ»öz©ïõ&û†l{ àô™–ê˜5C9—ì „<Ò˚“óﬂxÄ&_ÍÙQv¿jÄÔ∂Ê©og¡£ˆ4N¿d&SZùwêf^5§**MññÛ≤≥¿;V"º-Èg]üÜöZ®]ú∏RÚër ºÍ¬‰ ˜®ÀÎ3>Ÿ’ÆX´:öv£äCKÄƒFÇÏäâ4:µòß≠,‡<Ü9'rîàπ1ê»i|∑πç™∞¥;
```

I am trying to test my encoding and I am only getting the first value of my first key in the dictionary back as `b"[{'AP891220-0001': {1}}, {'AP891220-0034': {512}}, {'AP891220-0073': {311}}, {'AP891220-0078': {231}}, {'AP891220-0079': {137}}]"` This is my code for decoding:

```
f = open('inverted_indexes/id_1.txt', 'rb')
decompressed_data = zlib.decompress(f.read())
print(decompressed_data)
```

I am not sure what is the issue and why I am only decoding a small part of the .txt file rather than everything

Comment: I guess `zlib.compress(data)` writes some EOF (end-of-file) marker at the end of the blob. When reading, it stops at this cue.

Comment: Have a look at the [`zlib.Decompress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompressobj) object. It provides an [`unused_data`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.Decompress.unused_data) method which returns the remainder of what wasn't consumed in by zlib in a previous call to `Decompress.decompress()`.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your help. I am still super confused ...

Comment: Maybe you should use an easier-to-handle format then. I suggest [JSON lines](http://jsonlines.org/), but there are many options for storing structured data. If the file gets too large, you can compress it through Python's `gzip` library.

Answer (score 0):

Compress the whole dictionary at once using a serialization library like `pickle` (not secure), or `json`:

```
import zlib
import pickle

index = 'index.txt'

idf = dict(zip('abcdefghijklmnop',range(16)))

compressed_index = zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(idf))
with open(index, 'wb') as my_file:
    my_file.write(compressed_index)

with open(index, 'rb') as f:
    decompressed_data = zlib.decompress(f.read())
print(pickle.loads(decompressed_data))
```

```
import zlib
import json

index = 'index.txt'

idf = dict(zip('abcdefghijklmnop',range(16)))
compressed_index = zlib.compress(json.dumps(idf).encode())
with open(index, 'wb') as my_file:
    my_file.write(compressed_index)

with open(index, 'rb') as f:
    decompressed_data = zlib.decompress(f.read()).decode()
print(json.loads(decompressed_data))
```